# What is the best way to create buttons in Figma?

Tags: figma, button

I'm still learning Figma, and I'm having trouble to create inactive buttons (or other status, focus, hover etc) and swap when needed. Can someone help me?

The tutorials I found on the internet were not very clear to me!

[image]

Comment: where are you stuck? What have you tried? have you read this https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-simple-interactive-buttons-in-figma-in-2-steps-4e5510ab6687

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

- Create a button with Auto Layout
- Turn it into a component
- Add variant property to that component
- Inside the component set (dashed purple lines) duplicate your button
- Create one of the states you want like an inactive button
- Duplicate again and create your next button type (continue with the same process for all of your button needs)
- Name all variants properly. They shouldn't conflict.

And you are done.

To use them, call the component from the assets menu. You'll be able to swap between states.

You are welcome.